# Use HOC, React Context and componentDidMount API to get uid form Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, higher-order-components, react-context

I try to use a HigherOrderComponent (HOC) to provide the uid of a Firebase user to a component (Comp). The value is succesfully retrieved but I don't succeed in getting it in the wrapped component (Comp).
Below I describe the order of events in the HOC and wrapped Component (Comp):

HOC:
constructor() sets state.uid = null;
render() wraps the Comp in a Provider component with value=this.state.uid.
The Consumer component with prop uid={value} (where value is provided by the Provider component) wraps the Comp

In the componentDidMount() I make an asynchronous call to the Firebase backend (firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged()).

Comp:
render() fires;
componentDidMount() fires. this.props.uid is null because the asynchronous call didn't finish yet;

HOC:
in componentDidMount() the call to Firebase backend resolves. If not null I do this.setState({uid: value}) where value is the value from asynchronous call. That triggers a new render() of the HOC. A Provider component with the *new* value this.state.uid is returned.

Comp:
render() runs for 2nd time;
componentDidMount() *should* run so I can access the this.props.uid and use that value to retrieve data and other stuff but... this.props.uid is null.

I thought componentDidUpdate is supposed to run after a Component's render methode fires but here this doesn't happen. Setting breakpoints or console.log() shows this.

Funny thing is that when in the Comp render() method I display this.props.uid object (via JSON.stringify()) it shows! So the render method can access the updated props value but componentDidUpdate never...

What's wrong here? Am I missing something re: Reacts lifecycle methods?